# How to have the value of clicked button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to have the value of the button clicked. How can I extract the value with the refrenced function

```
class Calculator extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.selectedNumber=this.selectedNumber.bind(this);
}
selectedNumber(e){
    const option = e.value;
    console.log(option);
    alert(option);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>
                <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} name="option">1</button>
                <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} name="option">2</button>
                <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} name="option">3</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

when I want to click the referenced function with button's text value=1 , I want 1 and so on.

and I am getting this error ::::  "Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`."

Comment: Just do sample like this: onClick={(e) => this.selectedNumber(e)} then using e.target.textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element's text using : `e.target.textContent`

```
selectedNumber(e){
    const option = e.target.textContent;
    console.log(option);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as:

```
class Calculator extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.selectedNumber=this.selectedNumber.bind(this);
}
selectedNumber(n){
    const option = n;
    console.log(option);
    alert(option);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>
                <button onClick={() => this.selectedNumber(1)} name="option">1</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.selectedNumber(2)} name="option">2</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.selectedNumber(3)} name="option">3</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` attribute of each button:

```
class Calculator extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.selectedNumber=this.selectedNumber.bind(this);
    }
    selectedNumber(e){
        const option = e.target.value;
        console.log(option);
        alert(option);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>
                    <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} value={1} name="option">1</button>
                    <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} value={2} name="option">2</button>
                    <button onClick={this.selectedNumber} value={3} name="option">3</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `e` is event object, not the element

Comment: @charlietfl Doesn't the element's value get passed in with the event object? I know that's how text inputs work.

Comment: The element is `e.target` and `value` is property of the element not the event

Comment: This also worked but I am getting this error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: @ShivaChandel Read the warning carefully and do as it says.

Comment: @charlietfl ahh...I missed that from the OP's code. Thank you for the correction.